# Calculating Hard Disk Size

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I have a Seagate 1000GB SATA hard drive. The logical geometry of the hard drive is 16,383 cylinders, 16 heads and 63 sectors per track.

To my knowledge,

Capacity = Number of cylinders × number of heads × sectors/track × 512 = hard disk size (bytes)

For my specific hard disk my calculations are:

16,383 * 16 * 63 * 512 = 8455200768 bytes ~ 8.5gb
 it's too small comparing with original value.

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: CHS geometry has long since been outdated. Also, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing#CHS_conversion).

Comment: Where did you get the geometry figures from?

Comment: Your math is correct but the you have a parameter that is incorrect.  You don't take into account the number of platters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget CHS. Since LBA has come into play the physical geometry of a disk bares no relation to its actual geometry. The CHS geometry you mention is reported mainly to maintain legacy compatibility.

It is possible with some disks (and again, not in every situation) to map CHS to LBA, see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector#CHS_to_LBA_mapping

Also check out at fdisk's 'x' mode display, it shows the uninterpreted sizes